# panelGrid do JSF não funciona

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

O código abaixo deveria mostrar uma tela simples dividida entre os nomes e as áreas inputs, mas o panelGrid não está funcionando, o que há de errado? Ao executar não aparece nada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Cadastro de Automoveis</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>

                <h:outputLabel value="Marca:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.marca}"/><br/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Modelo:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.modelo}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Ano de Fabricação:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.anoFabricacao}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Ano do Modelo:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{automovelBean.automovel.anoModelo}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Observações:"/>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{automovelBean.automovel.observacoes}"/>

                <h:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{AutomovelBean.salva}"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Os elementos dentro do panelGrid devem ser todos elementos JSF. Texto puro não é elemento JSF, tente colocar os textos dentro do component `outputLabel`. Também não precisa colocar os elementos `br`, uma vez que panelGrid gera uma tabela (table).

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="marca" value="Marca:" />
                <h:inputText id="marca" value="#{automovelBean.automovel.marca}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="modelo" value="Modelo:" />
                <h:inputText id="modelo" value="#{automovelBean.automovel.modelo}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="anoFabricacao" value="Ano de fabricação:" />
                <h:inputText id="anoFabricacao" value="#{automovelBean.automovel.anoFabricacao}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="anoModelo" value="Ano do modelo:" />
                <h:inputText id="anoModelo" value="#{automovelBean.automovel.anoModelo}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="obs" value="Observações:" />
                <h:inputTextarea id="obs" value="#{automovelBean.automovel.observacoes}"/>

                <h:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{AutomovelBean.salva}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Agora não aparece mais nada na tela. Já verifiquei as bibliotecas, está tudo certo mas não aparece nada.

Comment: @EdsonFerreira edite sua pergunta e poste o seu novo código após a sugestão.

Answer (score 2):

os elementos devem estar dentro da tag  e para um melhor aninhamento, utilize o 'for'.

exemplo

```
<h:outputLabel for="txt" value="texto1"/>
<h:inputText id="txt value="#{seuBeam.texto1}"/>
```

também é válido utilizar o h:outputLabel vazio para ocupar um espaço na coluna do panelGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Depois que eu coloquei o "for", tudo sumiu, também:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  
<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">       
            <h:outputLabel for="id" Value="Id" />
            <h:inputText id="id" readonly="true"
                value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.id}"/>
        
            <h:outputLabel for="nome" Value="Nome" />
            <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.nome}"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="sobrenome" Value="Sobrenome" />
            <h:inputText
                id="sobrenome" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.sobrenome}"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="email" Value="Email" />
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.email}"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="login" Value="Login" />
            <h:inputText id="login" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.login}"/> 

            <h:outputLabel for="senha" Value="Senha" />
            <h:inputSecret id="senha" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.senha}"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="idade" Value="Idade" />
            <h:inputText id="idade" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.idade}"/>
            
        </h:panelGrid>      
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Vejo algumas pessoas usarem h:, às vezes p:.
A pessoa que me apresentou ao jsf (sou desenvolvedor .net), utiliza "h:" e funcionou bem.